# Invalid syntax in if test

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to check if several gdbs exists, but I keep getting an error. I really don't understand why and I have tried to check the separately and that works.

```
sti = r"C:\\DTM"
#DB
if arcpy.Exists(sti + "DB.gdb"):
    print ("DB.gdb finnes")
else:
    print ("DB.gdb finnes ikke, oppretter GDB")
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sti, "DB.gdb")

#DTM
if arcpy.Exists(sti + "DTM.gdb"):
    print ("DTM.gdb finnes")
else:
    print ("DTM.gdb finnes ikke, oppretter GDB")
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sti, "DTM.gdb")
```

I get this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 8
if arcpy.Exists(sti + "DTM.gdb"):
 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: First off, use `os.path.join` to concatenate a root path with a file geodatabase name. String addition can cause all manner of pain in this context. Secondly, the error you are reporting doesn't match the file you have provided. In general, we'll help with syntax errors, but the question is likely to be closed as *non-reproducible*, since it's unlike to help others. Be sure to check your file for extraneous nonprintable characters.

Comment: @GISGe That was just a copying error.

Comment: sti = r"C:\\DTM" is a raw string with an escaped backslash.. it's one or the other, either sti = r"C:\DTM" or sti = "C:\\DTM". As you've written it the value of sti is C:\\\\DTM which is a nonsensical path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sti + "DTM.gdb"` is not a valid path. Use `os.path.join()` to build your path:

```
import os

sti = r"path to GDBs"
#DB
if arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(sti, "DB.gdb")):
    print ("DB.gdb finnes")
else:
    print ("DB.gdb finnes ikke, oppretter GDB")
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sti, "DB.gdb")

#DTM
if arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(sti, "DTM.gdb")):
    print ("DTM.gdb finnes")
else:
    print ("DTM.gdb finnes ikke, oppretter GDB")
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sti, "DTM.gdb")
```

`os.path.join()` will add the apropriate path separators (slashes) between the different components of the path.

Comment: We weren't given the exact contents of `sti`; if it ended in a slash or backslash the resulting string could be valid (poor form, but valid). Using `os.path.join` wouldn't have any bearing on a syntax error.

Comment: @Vince you're indeed right

Comment: It probably worked because the edits removed an unprintable character.